# How to stream messages from Databricks to a Kafka client using Azure Event Hubs

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

I have a process that reads from a Kafka queue and writes into a DWH. The kafka queue is currently receiving data from a Java application, that reads from a local storage and writes into the Kafka queue.

We need to implement the following:

1. replace the local storage with an Azure Storage Account (DONE)
2. replace the Kafka queue with Azure Event Hubs
3. replace the java application with a Databricks simple job that does a readStream using Autloader from the Azure DataLake, and writes into the Azure Event Hubs

Constraint: the kafka client consumer cannot be changed, rather than its connection string.

Now, The good news is that Azure Event Hubs is Kafka-compliant (let's consider that the json body of each message is smaller than 10Kb), so my question is how to configure this architecture. More specifically:

- A) how should Azure EH be configured to be kafka-compliant towards its consumer?
- B) should I use kafka protocol also from Databricks to SEND the messages, or can I use it an Azure Event Hubs trusting the fact that it exposes itself with Kafka interface to the consumer, and with Event Hubs interface to the sender?
- C) where can I retrieve the kafka endpoint to be used from the consumer, and what should I care of in addition to the new connection string? In the listen policy I find Primary Key, Connection String and SAS Policy ARM ID but I'm not sure how to convert them to a Kafka enpoint

Answer (score 2):

To use EventHubs from Kafka protocol you need just configure Kafka options correctly. You need following:

- we need to get [Shared Access Signatures (SAS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-get-connection-string) to authenticate to Event Hubs topic - it should look like `Endpoint=sb://<....>.windows.net/;?...` and will be used as a password. For security reasons it's recommended to put it into a Databricks secret scope (update variables `secret_scope` and `secret_name` with your actual values).
- we need to form the correct string (the `eh_sasl` variable) for SASL (Simple Authentication and Security Layer) authentication - as a user name we're using static value `$ConnectionString`, and Event Hubs SAS is used as a password. SASL string looks a bit different on Databricks - instead of `org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule...` it should be prefixed with `kafkashaded.` as the original Java package is shaded to avoid conflicts with other packages.
- you need to provide the name of the Event Hubs namespace & topic from which to read data in `eh_namespace_name` and `topic_name` variables.

```py
secret_scope = "scope"
secret_name = "eventhub_sas"
topic_name = "topic1"
eh_namespace_name = "<eh-ns-name>"
readConnectionString = dbutils.secrets.get(secret_scope, secret_name)
eh_sasl = 'kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule' \
    + f' required username="$ConnectionString" password="{readConnectionString}";'
bootstrap_servers = f"{eh_namespace_name}.servicebus.windows.net:9093"
kafka_options = {
     "kafka.bootstrap.servers": bootstrap_servers,
     "kafka.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
     "kafka.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
     "kafka.request.timeout.ms": "60000",
     "kafka.session.timeout.ms": "30000",
     "startingOffsets": "earliest",
     "kafka.sasl.jaas.config": eh_sasl,
     "subscribe": topic_name,
}
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka") \ 
    .options(**kafka_options).load()
```

Writing is done with the similar configuration.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, to_json

# work with your dataframe
kafka_options = {
     "kafka.bootstrap.servers": bootstrap_servers,
     "kafka.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
     "kafka.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
     "kafka.sasl.jaas.config": eh_sasl,
     "topic": topic_name,
}
df.select(to_json(struct("*")).alias("value")) \
  .write.format("kafka").options(**kafka_options).save()
```

See more details about Spark + Kafka in the [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) & [Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/structured-streaming/kafka) documentation.

Comment: Thank you @Alex Ott. But I'm not sure if this answers my need; in fact, I don't need to READ from Databricks using a Kafka protocol, but I need to WRITE from Databricks so I was wondering if I may do it leveraging the Event Hubs protocol, while I read from the same event Hub using Kafka protocol and the kafka client. If I well understand, I should build the eh_sasl string and the kafka options you reported, am I right?

Comment: Yes. All magic is about that Kafka options. You can write them for writing as well

Comment: added a write example

Comment: fantastic, problem solved. Let me please just ask you confirmation if it's MANDATORY to write using kafka options when I read with a kafka protocol, or if it could write using an event hubs protocol (df.writeStream().format("eventhubs")). Thanks again

Comment: @MauroMinella There is no "eventhubs" Spark format, so yes `"kafka"` is mandatory.

Comment: Technically speaking, there is a separate connector for EventHubs that could be installed as a library and that provides `eventhubs` format. But it's less stable and performant than Kafka connector, so I always recommend to use Kafka connector with Kafka

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt thanks for such a detailed and useful answer. I implemented the code you suggested to write into the queue, however I had to create another question on stackovervlow because the Databricks process keeps showing "streaming initializing" and then fails with a generic error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75279183/databricks-streaming-from-delta-to-kafka-keeps-showing-stream-initializing