# Databricks streaming from DELTA to KAFKA keeps showing "Stream initializing..."

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, databricks, azure-eventhub

I used Autoloader to implement an ingestion process from the RAW layer (in normal parquet files) into a BRONZE layer (DELTA). I'm getting from 1 to 2,000 files per minute, for a total amount of about 10 million records per hour in total, since some files contain just one record while others contain several thousand records each. This process works well with a 4+1 cluster made of DS3V2 virtual machines on Azure.

Now I need to read from the same bronze layer, and send the data to a Kafka queue. So I provisioned an EventHub queue and implemented the following code:

```
bootstrap_servers = f"{eh_namespace_name}.servicebus.windows.net:9093"
 
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, to_json
 
df_for_kafka_bronze_streaming_wt = (spark
    .readStream
    .format("delta")
    .load(bronze_root_wt)
    )
 
bronze_write_eh_sasl_wt = 'kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule' \
    + f' required username="$ConnectionString" password="{bronze_write_connection_string_wt}";'
    
bronze_write_kafka_options_wt = {
     "kafka.bootstrap.servers": bootstrap_servers,
     "kafka.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
     "kafka.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
     "kafka.sasl.jaas.config": bronze_write_eh_sasl_wt,
     "topic": bronze_topic_wt,
}
 
(
    df_for_kafka_bronze_streaming_wt
    .select(to_json(struct("*")).alias("value"))
    .writeStream
    .trigger(processingTime="60 seconds")
    .format("kafka")
    .option("checkpointLocation", bronze_checkpoint_kafka_wt)
    .outputMode("append")
    .options(**bronze_write_kafka_options_wt)
    .start()
)
```

It seems that it works, in fact about 15 minutes (not less) after I run the command above,  the queue starts receiving messages. However the problem is that, even after 5 hours, the command above keeps saying "Stream initializing..." and sometimes after a few more hours, it stops with a generic error or an "out of memory" error even if the cluster log don't report any issues
[image]

The export from bronze to kafka is run on another identical cluster (4+1 DS3V2, dedicated to this task).

I suppose I my bronze dataframe is outputting in a wrong way, but I need some help to better troubleshooting this error.

Comment: can you try to add `.option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)` to the `spark.readStream` ? It could be that you have too much data so processing of first microbatch takes too long