# Streaming job to write data from delta table to event hub failing in databricks - Timeout issue

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub, delta-lake

Here is my code to write data from a delta table to event hub (from where consumer team will consume data):

```
import org.apache.spark.eventhubs._  
    import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger._  
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._  
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._  
    import java.util.Properties  
    import com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.{ EventData, PartitionSender }  
    import org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsConf  
    import io.delta.tables._  
    import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger  
    import java.io.PrintWriter  
    import java.time.ZonedDateTime  
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter  
    import scala.concurrent.duration._  
    import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}    

    // Configure Azure Event Hub details  
    val namespaceNameOut = "des-ent-prod-cus-stream-eventhub-001"  
    val eventHubNameOut = "hvc-prodstats-output"  
    val sasKeyNameOut = "writer"  
    val sasKeyOut = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="deskvscope", key="des-ent-prod-cus-stream-e venthub-001-writer")  

    // Configure checkpoint and bad data paths
    val checkpoint_dir_path = "/mnt/hvc-wenco/prodstats/stream/checkpoints"
    val baddata_path = "/mnt/hvc-wenco/prodstats/stream/Bad_data"

    // Define timestamp checkpoint path  
    val tbl_version_timestamp_path = "/mnt/hvc-  wenco/equip_status_history_table/checkpoints/checkpoint"  

    // Configure other parameters  
    val MaxEvents = 5000  

    // Read the last checkpoint timestamp  
    val last_checkpoint_string = dbutils.fs.head(tbl_version_timestamp_path)  

    // Parse last checkpoint timestamp  
    val time_format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSz"  
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(time_format)  
    val last_checkpoint = ZonedDateTime.parse(last_checkpoint_string, formatter)  

    // Build connection to Event Hub  
    val connStrOut = new com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.ConnectionStringBuilder()  
            .setNamespaceName(namespaceNameOut)  
            .setEventHubName(eventHubNameOut)  
            .setSasKeyName(sasKeyNameOut)  
            .setSasKey(sasKeyOut)  
    val ehWriteConf = EventHubsConf(connStrOut.toString())  

    // Create a streaming dataframe from the Delta table  
    val InputStreamingDF =   
      spark  
        .readStream  
        .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)  
        .option("startingTimestamp", last_checkpoint_string)  
        .option("readChangeFeed", "true")
        .table("wencohvc.equip_status_history_table")  
    val dropPreTransform = InputStreamingDF.filter(InputStreamingDF("_change_type") =!= "update_preimage")  
    val operationTransform = dropPreTransform.withColumn("operation", when($"_change_type" === "insert", 2).otherwise(when($"_change_type" === "update_postimage", 4)))  

    val transformedDF = operationTransform.withColumn("DeletedIndicator", when($"_change_type" === "delete", "Y").otherwise("N"))  
    val finalDF = transformedDF.drop("_change_type", "_commit_version", "_commit_timestamp")  

    // Write to Event Hubs with retry and checkpointing  
    var retry = true  
    var retryCount = 0  
    val maxRetries = 3  

    while (retry && retryCount < maxRetries) {  
      try {  
        val stream = finalDF  
          .select(to_json(struct(/* column list */)).alias("body"))  
          .writeStream  
          .format("eventhubs")  
          .options(ehWriteConf.toMap)  
          .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_dir_path)  
          .trigger(Trigger.AvailableNow)  
          .start()  

        stream.awaitTermination()  
        retry = false  
      } catch {  
        case e: Exception =>  
          retryCount += 1  
          if (retryCount < maxRetries) {  
            val delay = 2.seconds * retryCount  
            println(s"Stream attempt $retryCount failed, retrying in ${delay.toSeconds} seconds...")  
            Thread.sleep(delay.toMillis)  
          }  
      }  
    }  

    // Write checkpoint  
    val emptyDF = Seq((1)).toDF("seq")  
    val checkpoint_timestamp = emptyDF.withColumn("current_timestamp", current_timestamp()).first().getTimestamp(1) + "+00:00"  
    dbutils.fs.put(tbl_version_timestamp_path, checkpoint_timestamp.toString(), true)
```

Problem is that it is timing out before the last command and last checkpoint command does not run. I have tried retrying mechanism as well, but still, it timeouts. the data volume is huge from the source, I don't want to stream duplicate data by running the notebook again and again, if proper checkpoint is not happening. how do i solve this issue??
I expect the job to run and store last checkpoint timestamp correctly, so it picks up form there in the next run, but it timeouts before the last command. the last command gets skipped a result. The error I am getting is:

```
ERROR: Some streams terminated before this command could finish!
Stream attempt 1 failed, retrying in 2 seconds...
Stream attempt 2 failed, retrying in 4 seconds...
retry: Boolean = true
retryCount: Int = 3
maxRetries: Int = 3
ERROR: Some streams terminated before this command could finish!
Command took 0.04 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

That could be related to the fact that EventHubs doesn't have support for AvailableNow trigger (see [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/issues/656)).  The workaround would be to use Kafka connector that is built-in into Databricks Runtime - it could be used with EventHubs Standard tier (and higher) - you just need to provide correct options as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75256571/how-to-stream-messages-from-databricks-to-a-kafka-client-using-azure-event-hubs/75257676#75257676).